# CRM 2013: New Ribbon Button to Cancel a Task

Tags: javascript, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We are on CRM 2013. The requirement is to get rid of the 'Close' button completely from the Task form, and then create a new button to cancel the Task. So when clicking on this button, the Task will be 'Save as Cancelled'.

I try to modify the customization.xml RibbonDiffXML as follow for Task entity:

```
</CustomAction>
      <CustomAction Id="nwp.task.Form.SaveAsCancelled.CustomAction" Location="Mscrm.Form.task.MainTab.Save.Controls._children" Sequence="55">
        <CommandUIDefinition>
          <Button Command="Mscrm.SaveAsCancelled" Id="nwp.task.Form.SaveAsCancelled" Image32by32="$webresource:nwp_/img/btn_CaseCloseDialog32.png" Image16by16="$webresource:nwp_/img/btn_CaseCloseDialog16.png" LabelText="$LocLabels:nwp.task.Form.SaveAsCancelled.LabelText" Sequence="55" TemplateAlias="o1" ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:nwp.task.Form.SaveAsCancelled.ToolTipTitle" ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:nwp.task.Form.SaveAsCancelled.ToolTipDescription" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CustomAction>
```

And here is the command definition for Mscrm.SaveAsCancelled. I found a built-in function in the CRM server under /_static/_common/scripts/RibbonActions.js

```
<CommandDefinition Id="Mscrm.SaveAsCancelled">
        <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.VisualizationPaneNotMaximized" />
    </EnableRules>
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.CanWriteSelected" />
      <DisplayRule Id="Mscrm.SelectedEntityHasStatecode" />
    </DisplayRules>
    <Actions>
      <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.deactivate" Library="/_static/_common/scripts/RibbonActions.js">
        <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControl" />
        <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences" />
        <CrmParameter Value="SelectedEntityTypeCode" />
        <IntParameter Value="2" />
      </JavaScriptFunction>
    </Actions>
      </CommandDefinition>
```

However the definition of the deactivate function in RibbonActions.js requires me to select some record items as follow:

```
Mscrm.GridRibbonActions.deactivate=function(gridControl,records,entityTypeCode,defaultCloseState,callback)

{Mscrm.GridCommandActions.deactivate(gridControl,records,entityTypeCode,defaultCloseState,callback)}
```

So when I click on the 'Cancel' button, it asks me to select a record first because it is a grid control. But if I remove the parameters to select certain records, then the button will not do anything.

Do you know if there is already a built-in cancel or SaveAsCancelled or deactivate function that do not need require to select a record first?

Appreciate your input!

Comment: I don't see how you can expect to use a method for cancelling a record without selecting it first, either by selecting in a grid and using the grid buttons, or opening the record so it is the only "selected" one and then using the buttons on the form ribbon.
Out of interest, does this mean you intend to leave all tasks open for all time, and only ever close those that are cancelled, not the ones that are completed?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam. I didn't know that there's no built-in function to cancel the Task, so we instead wrote a SOAP request to do so as suggested here, credit to Guru Prasad
http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.com/2013/02/change-record-status-using-javascript.html

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two esay-ish approaches which don't rely on reusing platform code:

1. add a new Two Values field to the `Task` (let's call it `new_cancelled`, Default value: No) and put it on the form(s) leaving it hidden.
2. create a Real Time Workflow, autorun it when the record changes
3. WF would operate like this (pseudocode)

```
    if new_cancelled doesn't contain data
        set new_cancelled = No
    if new_cancelled = Yes
        change status to cancelled
```

4. make your ribbon button invoke a custom javascript function which updates `new_cancelled` to Yes through OData

ALTERNATE APPROACH:

1. see above
2. create an `Action`, let's call it `SaveTaskAsCancelled` and run it after the record changes with `new_cancelled` passed in.
3. register a plugin on `SAveTaskAsCancelled`, checking `new_cancelled` (same logic: if it's null, set it to No, then if it's Yes then cancel the task)
4. see above

Comment: Thank you Alex for the good suggestion. Instead have written a custom function to cancel the Task now using SOAP requests.

We also put a rule on the button so that it displays when the form is not read-only.

However I notice that users can still cancel the Task when not all required fields are filled in. I'm still looking up a display rule that prevents this. Do you know if there is a display rule that could prevent users from cancelling the task when not all required fields are filled in?

Thanks much.

Comment: That would be `<ValueRule Field="your_field_name" InvertResult="true" Value="" />` aka `true if field is not empty` (one valuerule for each field, wrapped up in a `DisplayRule`)